# Removing duplicates using partition by SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to remove duplicates from a table:

```
;WITH cte as(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [specimen id]
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0 ) ) RN
         FROM   quicklabdump)
        delete from cte where RN>1
```

The column `quicklabdumpID` is the primary key.

I would like to know how to keep only the largest `quicklabdumpID` where there are multiple occurrences of `[specimen id]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change your order by to `quicklabdumpid DESC`.

```
WITH cte as(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [specimen id]
                            ORDER BY  quicklabdumpid DESC ) RN
  FROM   quicklabdump)
delete from cte where RN>1
```

Comment: thanks so much. can you please tell me is there any issue with clint's solution?

Comment: @I__ - It will do the same. There might be a difference in performance. If you want to know which one will be faster you have to test them on your data.

Answer (score 6):

No need for partition

```
delete q
  from quicklabdump q
  where exists
  (
    select *
      from quicklabdump q2
      where q2.[specimen id] = q.[specimen id] and
        q2.quicklabdumpID > q.quicklabdumpID
  )
```

Comment: just curious, are you deleting from `quicklabdump` here and @I__ is deleting from the `cte`?

Comment: @cctan - cte is an alias that is set up using the with statement.

Comment: @ClintGood thank you so much for this. can you please tell me will i need to run this several times if there are more than 2 duplicate [specimen id]s? for example spec123, spec123, and spec123, with quicklabdumpid 1, 2, 3

Comment: @I__ This will do it in one go. As the query says if there is a record that has the same specimen id as a record that has a bigger quicklabdumpID then delete it