# Delete duplicates but keep 1 with multiple column key

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, delete-row

I have the following SQL select. How can I convert it to a delete statement so it keeps 1 of the rows but deletes the duplicate?

```
select s.ForsNr, t.* 
from [testDeleteDublicates] s
join (
    select ForsNr, period,  count(*) as qty
    from [testDeleteDublicates]
    group by ForsNr, period 
    having count(*) > 1
) t on s.ForsNr = t.ForsNr and s.Period = t.Period
```

Comment: from which table u want to delete?

Comment: will u please show the data too or create a fiddle? Do you want to Keep the OLDEST record and delete new records from 'testDeleteDublicates' ? i.e Delete all other records which are added later and keep the older one?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag due to the usage of non-standard `[..]` "quoting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following:

**Method 1:**

```
DELETE FROM Mytable WHERE RowID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(RowID) FROM Mytable GROUP BY Col1,Col2,Col3)
```

**Method 2:**

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ForsNr, period 
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
         FROM   testDeleteDublicates)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1
```

Hope this helps!

**NOTE:**
*Please change the table & column names according to your need!*

Comment: We are only looking at a single table. No ID column

Comment: I have Updated my answer please check another method for the same!

Answer (score 0):

This is easy as long as you have a generated primary key column (which is a good idea). You can simply select the min(id) of each duplicate group and delete everything else - Note that I have removed the having clause so that the ids of non-duplicate rows are also excluded from the delete.

```
delete from [testDeleteDublicates]
where id not in (
    select Min(Id) as Id
    from [testDeleteDublicates]
    group by ForsNr, period 
)
```

If you don't have an artificial primary key you may have to achieve the same effect using row numbers, which will be a bit more fiddly as their implementation varies from vendor to vendor.

Comment: It deletes all my rows :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with 2 option.

1. [Add primary-key and delete accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985384/delete-duplicate-records-from-a-sql-table-without-a-primary-key)

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1103/delete-duplicate-rows-with-no-primary-key-on-a-sql-server-table/

'2. Use row_number() with partition option, runtime add row to each row and then delete duplicate row.

[Removing duplicates using partition by SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122468/removing-duplicates-using-partition-by-sql-server)

```
--give group by field in partition.
;with cte(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over( order by ForsNr, period partition ForsNr, period) RowNo , * from [testDeleteDublicates]
    group by ForsNr, period 
    having count(*) > 1
)

select RowNo from cte 
group by ForsNr, period
```